# Bulma Navbar-burger not collapsing the navbar item data

Tags: vue.js, navbar, bulma, buefy

Hi i am a newbie in vuejs, Buefy. I wanted to add navigation bar. Navigation Bar works in the desktop however when view it in mobile responsive when the burger click doesn't show anything. the navbar item not collapsible. can anyone help me? Thank you.

Here is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
      <div class="navbar-brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
        </a>
        
        <a
          role="button"
          class="navbar-burger burger"
          aria-label="menu"
          aria-expanded="false"
          data-target="navbarBasicExample"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item">Home</a>
          
          <a class="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

          <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
            <a class="navbar-link">More</a>

            <div class="navbar-dropdown">
              <a class="navbar-item">About</a>
              <a class="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
              <a class="navbar-item">Contact</a>
              <hr class="navbar-divider">
              <a class="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-end">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button is-primary">
                <strong>Sign up</strong>
              </a>
              <a class="button is-light">Log in</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";
export default {
  name: "App",
  mounted() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(
          document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-burger"),
          0
        );
        if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {
          $navbarBurgers.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener("click", () => {
              const target = el.dataset.target;
              const $target = document.getElementById(target);
              el.classList.toggle("is-active");
              $target.classList.toggle("is-active");
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Can access here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-khayyam-mnb7x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way you trying to do it is a bit different from the [official documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/navbar). In order to create a navbar you should wrap your whole navbar within a `<b-navbar>` like this:

```html
<b-navbar>
  <template slot="brand">
        <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
        </a>
  </template>
  <template slot="start">
        <div class="navbar-start">
          <a class="navbar-item">Home</a>
          <a class="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

          <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
            <a class="navbar-link">More</a>

            <div class="navbar-dropdown">
              <a class="navbar-item">About</a>
              <a class="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
              <a class="navbar-item">Contact</a>
              <hr class="navbar-divider">
              <a class="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </template>
  <template slot="end">
        <div class="navbar-end">
          <div class="navbar-item">
            <div class="buttons">
              <a class="button is-primary">
                <strong>Sign up</strong>
              </a>
              <a class="button is-light">Log in</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
   </template>
</b-navbar>
```

Then fill each slot with appropriate content of yours.

**Working DEMO:**

[image: CodeSandbox]

Comment: Just want to add `b-navbar-item` (internal links) and `b-navbar-dropdown` (menus)